# Manga where the main character gets killed by his village friend in the first chapter. Then he meets a dragon or a god

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find this manga about a dude who was killed by his village friend, then met a dragon or a god, something to change his power/abilities. Then he lived again.

Comment: This isn't much to go on. Please take a look at [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/122024) and see if you can recall any more details about the story or characters which you can then [edit] into your question.

Comment: Incidentally, though, I have to give you props for a very descriptive title rather than something generic like "looking for a manga". :)

Comment: Perhaps also take a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?rq=1) as well, and [edit] in anything else

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is *[Murabito desu ga Nani ka?](https://myanimelist.net/manga/104247/Murabito_desu_ga_Nani_ka)*, or *I Am a Villager, What About It?*

The main character and two of his friends are reincarnated into another world. Early on, the main character is killed, but the skill he had been given when reincarnating turned back time to when he was first reincarnated. He then used his knowledge of the future to get a dragon to train him.

I has been a while since i read this one, but i believe there was something of a love triangle between the three who reincarnated. I believe the other male killed the main character so he could romance the female member of the three.